# Implement a dark theme with Vite. more than 2 css files as output

Tags: css, bundle, vite, theming

I have a project in which I can change a **dark theme**. I realize this by simply replacing the **CSS** file created with **sass**.
Now I want to implement my project in **Vite**. But this creates only one **CSS** file.

What would be the better choice. The Theming completely revise so that I do not need 2 **CSS** files. Or set **Vite** so that I get 2 **CSS** files out.

My current **vite.config.js** looks like this:
This is not my final configuration. it is just some test

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
export default defineConfig({
    root: "src",
    assetsInclude: ["./assets/**/*.*"],
    build: {
        sourcemap: true,
        manifest: true,
        cssCodeSplit: true,
        emptyOutDir: true,
        outDir: "../dist"
    }
})
```

**With best regards StevoEs**